# How to Customize of onepagecheckout in Nopcommerce?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce, onepage-checkout

I am new to nopcommerce, I have successfully implemented onepage checkout plugin for payment checkout in nopcommerce.

I want to just change payment info option. 
want to show radio buttons with image instead of default dropdown on payment cart option.

But it is giving error when customize `paymentinfo.cshtml`

> "Error executing child request for handler
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'"

Default Code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CreditCardType, Model.CreditCardTypes, new { @class = "dropdownlists" })
```

Customized Code:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.CreditCardTypes)
 {                
        <h1> @item.CreditCardType</h1> 
        OR
        @Html.RadioButton(item.CreditCardType.ToString(), item.CreditCardType)
 }
```

Comment: It needs to be `<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.CreditCardType, item.CreditCardType, new { id = "" })<h1>@item.CreditCardType</h1></label>`

Comment: still it gives same errror "Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'."

Comment: That error has nothing to do with generating the radio buttons (which need to be as per the code in my previous comment)

Comment: Right, I have also changed render type from return View() to return Partical View(). still it is not solved.

Comment: That error can be caused by a number of issues, for example using `@Html.Action()` to call a child action which is marked with `[HttpGet]` (and the error happens if you POST and return the view

Comment: It is solved by simple modification in Radiobuttion Binding. This error occurs only when syntax error or unproper binding of control.